# My front wheel was steering to the right... now it's steering to the left. What's the cause of this?

Tags: front

I already tried removing the cables that might pull it to the left. Still the same. I straightened the seat. I aligned the wheel properly. It's starting to annoy me. I cant ride my bike right. All the shops I visited told me to replace my bearings, which I did. It still it steers to the left. What else could it be?

Comment: It could be your posture placing your centre-of-gravity off the centreline of the bike. Have you tested any other bikes?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We ask that you [write to the best of your ability](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on this site. This means proper capitalization, proper punctuation, and complete sentences. I have made some edits for you. If you feel I have inadvertently changed the nature of your question, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Define "steers to the left".  Do you mean when you take your hands off the handlebar?  Does it happen only when pedaling  or when you're coasting and relatively "neutral" in body posture?

Comment: Is the fork bent? Look carefully at the gap between tire and fork; is it even on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Factors that have an impact on the steering include external forces and internal forces. External forces include things like cables, the riders centre of gravity and forces coming from the wheel (out of true, dead hub bearing). Internal forces have to do with the headset itself, if the bearing cups are not parallel, if the adjustment is incorrect, if a foreign object made its way into the headset, if there is pitting in the bearing cups. A bent steerer could also be it.

If you have eliminated the cable pulling (or pushing) as a problem, and your wheel is true, try adjusting the headset bearings. They should be as loose as possible without having any play or knocking. A dead bearing on one side of your hub would probably have a negligible contribution. If you've done that and it's still a problem, I would suspect the seating of the bearings not being parallel or the
 steerer tube not being perfectly straight.